# Ubuntu 18.04 Login Problem - How to type a Russian username with a German keyboard on TTY

Tags: keyboard, login, keyboard-layout

I turned on my laptop and I got a black login screen looking like this:

```
<"computername"> login:
```

As I think you have to type your username their and then confirm with your password. The problem is that my username on this laptop is written with russian letters, but I got a german keyboard, so I was wondering how I could login now, lol.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/tips-specialchars.html#ctrlshiftu

Comment: Hey thank you for ur fast reply but when I type ctrl + shift + u and then holding ctrl + shift down to type and then type the 4 digit code I just get the special symbols if you type shift + the number, so at the end I dont get the unicode symbol

Comment: Don't hold <Ctrl>+<Shift> down. Just release <Ctrl>+<Shift>+<U>, then the code, then <Enter> or <Space>.

Comment: If I do this the 4 digit code appears and after pressing space nothing happens and after pressing enter I have to enter my password

Comment: Hmm.. Probably it only works in a graphical environment (Gtk or Qt) and not in a raw TTY. Then I'm out of ideas, sorry.

Comment: Anyways I appreciate your help